# Addition of any number of columns in each loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Example:

```
dict1 = ({'ROADS' : ['STREETNAME', 'LEFTFROM', 'LEFTTO', 'RIGHTFROM', 'RIGHTTO'],
            'ITA' :  ['I.ID_BOUND', 'I.BOUND_IDQ']})
```

**Note**

`ROADS,ITA` are the files
the rest are their columns.

I want to do an addition like concat of all the columns in every file.
The problem is that each file has different number of columns.

How to make it do it with this?

**Update**

Explanation:

how to make it add any number of columns that may exist in the dictionary?
This following example tries to explicitly refer to each column as v[0],etc
What I want is to do it no matter the number of columns so to just takes independently of the number.

I tried:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    newfield = v[0] + v[1]
```

Comment: Please provide what you expect the result to look like

Comment: Assuming you are using Pandas, are you looking to concatenate column **labels** or column **data** across dataframes?

Comment: the latter is true

Comment: @user51332, Where is your underlying data stored, in another dictionary such as `{'ROADS': df1, 'ITA': df2, ...}`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works:

```
newfields = {}

for k,v in dict1.items():
    newfields[k] = ''.join(v)
```

Comment: will this create a concatenated field in each dataset with its related columns?

Comment: Not really. Just concatenates the strings in the dictionary in the code snippet that you posted. It would be great if you improve your question with the Pandas dataset stuff that you need.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is that what you understood?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to use a dictionary comprehension:

`new_dict = {key: ','.join(value) for key, value in dict1.items()}`

results in:
`{'ROADS': 'STREETNAME,LEFTFROM,LEFTTO,RIGHTFROM,RIGHTTO', 'ITA': 'I.ID_BOUND,I.BOUND_IDQ'}`

or you can replace the `,` in the `','.join` to use whatever separator you like

#### Update based on explanation:

`list_fields = [''.join(value) for key, value in dict1.items()]`

results in: `['STREETNAMELEFTFROMLEFTTORIGHTFROMRIGHTTO', 'I.ID_BOUNDI.BOUND_IDQ']`

Still not sure what you are trying to achieve.

list and dictionary comprehension is traditionally faster than a for loop

Comment: will this create a concatenated field in each dataset with its related columns?

Comment: what do you mean by "concatenated field"? can you give an example of what output you are expecting?

Comment: I have updated the question. Is that what you understood?

Comment: no, you need to provide sample expected output otherwise we will all continue to guess and eventually give up and stop helping you.

Comment: I just want to know how to make it in each loop to take all the columns for every file without explicitly stating the indexes of the columns. Don't focus on the outcome. The logic is what I am searching.If you can write in a non list comprehension version to be more understandable. Thanks

Comment: just use a `join` then - without understanding the outcome and the difficulty in understanding your question, I am afraid I cannot help. good luck